# scrapy/Python crawls but does not scrape data

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

As a novice to scrapy, I could not figure out why this spider does not crawl data from a website to crawl. I have searched across stackoverflow for possible answers, but i see that it is not adequately addressed. I am trying to scrape a small town-restaurant listing from the website. I have no detailed knowledge of the security features of the website to scrape.Is the problem associated with the XPath selection elements?The spider runs fine, except it does not scrape anything. Can you please suggest why it does not scrape and how to solve the problem. The spider has the following code:

```
try:
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.http import Request

except ImportError:
    print ("\nERROR IMPORTING THE NESSASARY LIBRARIES\n")

#scrapy.optional_features.remove('boto')


class YelpSpider(Spider):
    name = 'yelp_spider'
    allowed_domains=["yelp.com"]
    headers=['venuename','services','address','phone','location']

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = ['https://www.yelp.com/springfield-il-us']

    def start_requests(self):
        requests = []
        for item in self.start_urls:
            requests.append(Request(url=item, headers={'Referer':'http://www.google.com/'}))
            return requests

    def parse(self, response):
        requests=[] 
        sel=Selector(response)
        restaurants=sel.xpath('//*[@id="wrap"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/h1')
        items=[]
        for restaurant in restaurants:
            item=YelpRestaurantItem()
            item['venuename']=sel.xpath('//*[@id="wrap"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/h1')
            item['services']=sel.xpath('//*[@id="wrap"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/a[1]')
            item['address']=sel.xpath('//*[@id="wrap"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/strong/address')
            item['phone']=sel.xpath('//*[@id="wrap"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/span[3]')
            item['location']=sel.xpath('//*[@id="dropperText_Mast"]')
            item['url']=response.url
            items.append(item)
            yield item
```

My items.py has the following code:

```
import scrapy

class YelpRestaurantItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    url=scrapy.Field()
    venuename = scrapy.Field()
    services = scrapy.Field()
    address = scrapy.Field()
    phone = scrapy.Field()
    location=scrapy.Field()
```

[image: scrapy-code-does-not-scrape-any-data]

Comment: I assume you are having indentation issues, please correct your code in the question. And, have you tried debugging your code? maybe printing something in every iteration of `for restaurant ...`?

Comment: What are you trying to scrape? The spider searches for something with an id attribute that is "wrap" but when I open the start url I don't find anything that matches this.

Comment: @Casper , I am trying to scrape name,services,address, phone,location. I should also say, this is my first time using xpath and scrapy.I just copied the xpath for a restaurant that was highlighted in Chrome/Developer Tools. However, I wanted to scrape a list of restaurant businesses in this small town namely name,services,address, phone and location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imports didn't work that well over here, but that might be a configuration issue on my side. I think the scraper below does what you're searching for:

```
import scrapy

class YelpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yelp_spider'
    allowed_domains=["yelp.com"]
    headers=['venuename','services','address','phone','location']

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = ['https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=Springfield%2C+IL&ns=1']

    def start_requests(self):
        requests = []
        for item in self.start_urls:
            requests.append(scrapy.Request(url=item, headers={'Referer':'http://www.google.com/'}))
            return requests

    def parse(self, response):
        for restaurant in response.xpath('//div[@class="biz-listing-large"]'):
            item={}
            item['venuename']=restaurant.xpath('.//h3[@class="search-result-title"]/span/a/span/text()').extract_first()
            item['services']=u",".join(line.strip() for line in restaurant.xpath('.//span[@class="category-str-list"]/a/text()').extract())
            item['address']=restaurant.xpath('.//address/text()').extract_first()
            item['phone']=restaurant.xpath('.//span[@class="biz-phone"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['location']=response.xpath('.//input[@id="dropperText_Mast"]/@value').extract_first()
            item['url']=response.url
            yield item
```

Some explanation:

I've changed the start url. This url actually provides an overview of all restaurants while the other did not (or at least not when viewed from my location).

I've removed the pipeline as it was not defined in my system and I couldn't try it out with the non-existent pipeline in the code.

The parse function is the one I made the real changes to. The xpaths you defined weren't very clear. Now the code loops over each listed restaurant.

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="biz-listing-large"]')
```

This code captures all the restaurants data. I've used this in a for loop, so we can perform actions for each restaurant. This data is available in the variable `restaurant`.

So if I want to extract data from a restaurant, I use this variable. In addition, we need to start the xpath with a `.` because the script will otherwise start from the beginning of the webpage (which would be the same as using response).

In order to understand the xpaths in my answer, I could explain this to you but there is a lot of documentation available and they're probably better in explaining this than I am.

[Some documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp)

[And some more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note that I've used restaurant for most values of `item`. Values from location and url are not really restaurant data but are located elsewhere on the webpage. This is why those values use `response` instead of `restaurant`.

Comment: Thank you for your dedicated answer, It worked, although It didn't scrape 'phone' and 'address',may be syntax error?

Comment: Did you make any alterations to the code? When I run the crawler over here it returns all defined properties of item.

Comment: Code used as you suggested, It populates the other fields except 'phone' and 'address'.

Comment: You might want to try running the script with `-L DEBUG`. When you do, find the scraped data in the logs and see whether the address and phone are in there. Since the data is returned properly over here I'm guessing it has to do with some other settings of Scrapy.